# Data type of array in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, blob

I have  a variable of type array and I want to store it as it is in database(mysql) and when I apply tinyblob that I usually use  in java for display it return abnormal output.
So what is the correct datatype for the array in php.

```
$countryGoup=array("USA","FRANCE","GERMANY","BRITAIN");
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could:

### 1) use a SET datatype if the values are few and fixed

You define the column in the `CREATE TABLE` statement as `SET('USA', 'France', 'Germany', ...) NOT NULL` (not null optional), and use queries like:

```
INSERT INTO myTable SET countries="USA,Germany";
```

---

### 2) use a lookup table with a foreign reference

So you define a `countries` table:

```
id_country|name
----------+-----------
1         |USA
2         |Germany
3         |France
```

and define a **pivot table** that links your main object (f.ex. "users") to the countries, thus esabilishing a **many-to-many relationship**.

F.ex., a `users_countries` table would link `users` table to `countries` table in this way:

```
id_user|id_country
------------------
1      |1
1      |2
2      |1
```

In this example, user 1 is linked to countries with id 1 and 2 (USA and Germany), user 2 is linked to USA only, and so on

---

### 3) use a comma-separated string, or other separators, or serialize the array

This involves using the server-side language (in your case PHP) to concat the values with some separator (such as comma `,` or pipe `|`):

```
$countries = array("USA", "Russia", "Iran");
$countriesString = implode (",", $countries); // $countriesString = "Usa,Russia,Iran"
$query = "INSERT INTO mytable SET countries = '" . $countriesString . "'";
```

> (Note: the string value is not escaped for example purpose, but it is not a good practice)

When you *retrieve* the value from the db, you retrive the string you put into, and obtain again an array with `$array = explode(",", $retrievedValueFromDb)`, providing the same separator.

**Update:**

### 4) Retrieve values find_in_set() MySQL function

You can rely also on the `find_in_set(needle, field)` function, that returns an integer greater than zero if the string is present in a comma-separated value field.

So if you use approach 1) and have a string field like `"USA,Germany"`, you can obtain the columns in which `USA` is present by using:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE find_in_set('USA', countries) <> 0
```

---

**Approach 1)** works if you have few fixed values, also very easy on queries. Downside is that you are limited to 64 values, that the values must be fixed, and the cannot contain a comma (,) as its used as a separator.

**Approach 2)** is the most standardized and correct, it's also normalized and query-efficient

**Approach 3)** is easy but requires extra processing and is not so easy for SQL

As stated elsewhere, there **is no "array" datatype** in the dbms, you have to use some workaround.

Comment: The datatype I want is the one to be used to the column that will hold the array in database

Comment: Yes, but *there is not* an "array" datatype in mysql. You have to resort to one of these workarounds.